# How to make my carousel active for each item?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, carousel

---

I want to make one image active each when it is selected, but right now all items are active

```
<?php foreach($project_images as $image) {?>

    <?php
        if($image['project_image_name'] != '') {
            $images = '<img src="'.base_url().'public/uploads/project_images/'.$image['project_category'].'/'.$image['project_id'].'/'.$image['project_image_name'].'" >';
        } else {
            $images = '<img src="'.base_url().'public/uploads/project_images/default/default-project-image.jpg'.'" ';
        }
    ?>

    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <?php echo $images; ?>
    </div>

<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for JavaScript, not PHP.

I'm assuming PHP doesn't know if the image is active or not, it just displays the image.

I'm assuming you want the image to be active when it's clicked.  That's JavaScript.

**Step 1: Don't make anything active.**

Remove 'active' from the div.

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <?php echo $images; ?>
</div>
```

**Step 2: Give each div a unique identifier** so JavaScript knows what element you're referring to.

```
<?php 
   $id = 0;
   foreach($project_images as $image) {
     $id++;
 ?>

    <?php
         // .. code is the same
    ?>

    <div id="carousel_<?php echo $id ?>" class="carousel-item">
        <?php echo $images; ?>
    </div>

<?php }?>
```

That should give each div a unique id.

**Step 3: Create a JavaScript function** that will toggle the 'active' class of the selected item.

Ex:

```
function ToggleClass(elemID){
  // Get selected element
  selElement = document.getElementById(elemID);

   //Use selElement to change class.  Code goes here
}
```

**Step 4: Add the JavaScript function to the div.**

Note the quotes -- use the double and singles as needed.

Ex:

```
<div id="carousel_<?php echo $id ?>" class="carousel-item active" onclick="ToggleClass('carousel_<?php echo $id ?>')">
      <?php echo $images; ?>
 </div>
```